# Why is this random black minimized window box appearing on my desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10

This is the what I see when I first power on my PC:

[image: the black box minimized]

And this is what I see after I maximize it:

[image: the black box maximized]

I have no idea what this is and how to remove it or what's causing it and I just noticed it, so I don't know how long it had been there.

Comment: With the box on the screen, run Task Manager and see what the app is or see if there is an unidentified app.

Comment: I have hundreds of process running, can not pinpoint what this is as it doesn't let me right click on it even. I also tried WindowFocusLogger but it doesn't seem to be picking up anything either, ran anti-virus scan multiple times, also nothing

Comment: I did press Alt + space + c and the box is gone but its back after restart :/

Comment: Run a full virus scan with Windows Defender.

Comment: I did, nothing came out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended this task by manually ending process:
voicecontrolengine.exe

To make voicecontrolengine.exe show in Task Manager, sometimes you have to attempt to resize the small dot on your desktop.

.exe always launches on boot, unsure where or how to stop this.
Is not in any boot list.

Bundled with a recent update of MSI Dragon Center, though can't find anything in configs to stop it launching.

Comment: this is the cause, hopefully msi fixes this

Comment: Thanks. I was getting suspicious of this!!

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a CMD prompt from a task run at startup, perhaps a batch file. Use Sysinternals' [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to see what runs at startup. In particular, check what happens at *Logon* and in *Scheduled Tasks*.

Comment: will do when I get home, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely something that is using the command line to load itself, be sure to check which applicaions are launching at startup, or right a login.
You can do this through the Task manager, then go to startup, and disable, or enable any applicatons that you need to.